# PHP and JQuery - PHP json_encoded 2D array doesn't arrive in JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to create a demo to get data from a PHP script that runs a SQL query, takes the associated array and json_encodes's it and returns it to the JQuery ajax caller in the calling php file. For some reason it never arrives (check with Firebug). But if I manually create a 2D array, json_encode it, it works fine. I am completely stumped why my array never makes it from SQL but it does if I just hand type it. I have diffed the resulting strings and they are exactly the same.

Code:

```
...snip...
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getclients.php",
        data: { username: $('#staff_list').val() },
        //contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(results) {
            console.log("results");
        },
        fail: function() {
            console.log("fail!!");
        },
        error: function(r, e, m) {
            console.log("error");
            //console.dir(r);
            console.log(e + ', ' + m);
        }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("done");
        //console.log(data);
    });
    console.log("done with change detection...");    
...snip...
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
error_reporting(0); // prevents a notice from breaking ajax
//session_start();
$username = $_GET['username'];
$json = array();
$test = array(
    array("id"=>4,"first_name"=>"Miles","last_name"=>"O'Brian"),
    array("id"=>5,"first_name"=>"Jean Luc","last_name"=>"Picard"),
    array("id"=>6,"first_name"=>"Reginald","last_name"=>"Barclay")
          );

$mysqli = new mysqli('mydomain', 'myuser', 'mypassword', 'mydb');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id`, `first_name`, `last_name` FROM client WHERE provider_username = ?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();


    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $json[] = $row;
    }

    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
echo json_encode($json);
echo json_encode($test);// this works
?>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. I am new to PHP but not to programming so I tried everything I can think of (including the manual and Google) and am just completely stumped.

Comment: have to tried to turn on the error reporting? and check? and instead of `console.log('results')`, you actually put the response instead `console.log(results)` (without the quotes)?

Comment: Do you have any users with the exact username 's'? You're using "=" in your sql where it looks like you might mean "like"

Comment: Here is an exact copy of the resulting dataset json_encode'ed from SQL: [{"id":7,"first_name":"Tom","last_name":"Cruise"},{"id":8,"first_name":"John","last_name":"Cusak"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem. The line in the Ajax where I set the data:

```
data: { username: $('#staff_list').val() }
```

is causing the problem. For some reason it is getting an array, making the line

```
data: { username: $('#staff_list').val()[0] }
```

fixes the problem.

Comment: Remember: every jQuery DOM selector function `$(something)` returns an array; `$('#staff_list').first().val()` is what you probably wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your result set here which is return by the satement.
$result->fetch_assoc().

Please check your php version. Because the adding array element by using shorten method as you have used in your code "$json[] = $row;" is available in PHP 5.4. Look [document](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) for more information.

Second option if it is not available in your PHP version then you can achieve it as: 
array_push($json,$row); instead of $json[] = $row;

Comment: Here is the print_r'ed output of that array: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [first_name] => Tom
            [last_name] => Cruise
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => Cusak
        )

)